# How to compute (some) landscape fragmentation index

Tags: r, raster, imagej, qgis, fragmentation

I am working with rasters of forests and need to compute (some) fragmentation index.

I am looking for  **"single-value" index** for each raster. My first try was to do it in `QGis` but desirable plugin (`LecoS – Land cover analytics`) is damaged. Also I tried to do it in `R` and in `ImageJ` but I can not find any suitable package/plugin or function. I am running out of options.

Can you please **recomend** some software (Linux preffered)?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to calculate? any particular metric?

Comment: some metric which will reflect the ratio between the area of patches to the length of forest edges of patches.

Comment: Do you know [SDMTools Tools](https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/SDMTools/PatchStat.html)?

Comment: Thanks! There are many metrics ! PatchID, n.cell, n.core.cell, n.edges.perimeter, n.edges.internal, area, core.area, perimeter, perim.area.ratio, shape.index, frac.dim.index, core.area.index.